# Error with importShapefile with PBSmapping package in R

Tags: r, gis, shapefile, polygons

I am receiving a sporadic error message with importShapefile in PBSmapping (version 2.63.37) in RStudio (0.97.318), running R version 2.15.2, platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit). I also received the error while running previous versions of R and RStudio.

```
> ST6 = importShapefile("Data/pvi_stat_2002_utm.shp", projection="UTM", readDBF = TRUE)
Error in 1:nrow(dbf) : argument of length 0

> traceback()
2: cbind(1:nrow(dbf), dbf)
1: importShapefile("Data/pvi_stat_2002_utm.shp", projection = "UTM",readDBF = TRUE)
```

I only receive this error occasionally - perhaps 1 in every 10 times that I run the code. But once the error occurs in a session, it occurs repeatedly and will not successfully implement the command until I have closed R completely and reopened it. On one occasion I had to reboot the computer for it to work, as successive reopening of R did not help.

I thought it might be a memory issue but sometimes I will get the error when no objects are in the workspace. And usually the code runs fine even if I have large objects loaded. In response to the error I have removed all objects from the workspace and even followed with gc(), but to no avail.

This is the only shapefile with which I have received the error but as it is the only one that I use with regularity and since I can not predict when the error will occur, my efforts with other shapefiles are inconclusive. Not sure about uploading a shapefile to Stack Overflow. The zipped file is about 9MB.

Comment: a classic case where you should use seq_len(nrow(dbf)) rather than 1:nrow(dbf)

Comment: Try importShapefile("..shp", projection="UTM", readDBF = FALSE) that might avoid the immediate error and get you the geometry. rgdal also reads shapefiles as well as maptools, rgdal gives you projection metadata if it's there, while maptools cannot (since it cannot convert from the WKT in .prj to PROJ.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in the folder where your shapefile is. Is there actually a `.dbf` file? If there is, it sounds like it is empty or corrupted, or misnamed. Are you expecting your shapefile to have polygons with attributes. Can you try `importShapefile(... readDBF = FALSE )`? Maybe you can make our data available through a dropbox link or something?

Alternatively have you tried `rgdal:::readOGR` or, my personal favourite, `maptools:::readShapePoly()`. I personally find `readShapePoly()` to be extremely robust and there are methods for coercing a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` from `sp` to a `PolySet` from PBS.

If you really must use PBS have you tried...

```
require( maptools )
require( sp )
myshp <- readShapePoly("Data/pvi_stat_2002_utm")
myshpPBS <- SpatialPolygons2PolySet( myshp )
```

I am assuming that there is a `.prj` file with your shapefile, describing the projection information?

Comment: @Jordan Where? I don't see it!

Comment: Thanks! A dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ckgtyvtjh6z27km/6HaDADQ0J8.  I'd prefer to stick w/PBSmapping b/c of subsequent processing, if possible. I could start over but since importShapefile works about 9 out of 10 times, I'm a bit hesitant. I've tried read.DBF=F but that did not remove the error. Also, I need the DBF data (though I could later read in the dbf data and rejoin to the PolyData) for processing. I can use the SpatialPolygons2PolySet route though that seems to omit my other data fields (which again, I could rejoin afterwards). Weird that it USUALLY works fine. @SimonO101

Comment: Sorry @SimonO101 - this is my first post and I hadn't realized that the enter key would submit my comment.

Comment: @Simon0101 - your suggestions for work arounds were great. Thanks. I also thought I would follow-up for any one that experiences the same issue. With more recent updates to the PBSmapping package and several dependencies, the error seems to have simply disappeared...so if you have the same problem, version 2.65.49 PBSmapping should alleviate it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using R-3.0.1 and PBS Mapping 2.66.53 with the NAVO Divisions shapefile from http://www.nafo.int/about/overview/gis/Divisions.zip.  On Windows 7 x86_64 and OS X Snow Leopard (using macports R built for x86_64), the .dbf is being read properly, but it
sometimes fails using RHEL 5.9:

```
> library("PBSmapping", lib.loc="/home/gwhite/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0")

-----------------------------------------------------------
PBS Mapping 2.66.53 -- Copyright (C) 2003-2013 Fisheries and Oceans Canada

[...]
-----------------------------------------------------------

> library("rgeos", lib.loc="/home/gwhite/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.0")
 rgeos version: 0.2-19, (SVN revision 394)
 GEOS runtime version: 3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8 
 Polygon checking: TRUE 

> layer='Divisions'
> divs = importShapefile(layer, projection='LL')
Error in 1:nrow(dbf) : argument of length 0
```

Using `readDBF=F` does allow the shapefile data to be read:

```
> divs = importShapefile(layer, projection='LL', readDBF=F)
```

So far, `importShapefile()` has been working in a freshly started R session.